# Why is migration lookup failing during synchronisation of Group entities?

Tags: 8, group, migrations

On the basis of an RSS feed, I am required to create Group entities and Users out of the feed's items.

Each item contains sufficient data:

```
<item>
  <id>123</id>
  <title>An example</title>
  <description>Some &lt;strong&gt;HTML&lt;/strong&gt; description.</description>
  <author>John Doe</author>
  <email>john.doe@example.com</email>
  <pub_date>09/19/2017 - 08:30</pub_date>
</item>
```

I am using Core's migration module along with migrate_plus and migrate_tools and wrote two migration yml files, one for creating Group entities out of the items and one to generate users out of the author & email fields.

Taken separately, both work fine, that is I am getting Group entities and User entities as expected. The only issue which I can't get my head wrapped around is to set the respective User to be the Group's owner.

Here's the processing part of the Group yml file:

```
process:
  uid:
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: migrate_plus.migration.users
    no_stub: true
    source: email
  label: title
  field_description: description
  created:
    plugin: format_date
    from_format: 'm/d/Y - H:i'
    to_format: 'U'
    source: pub_date
  status:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: my_group_type

migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - migrate_plus.migration.users
```

All fields except for `uid` are set correctly. If I change the user id process part to something static like

```
  uid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
```

it works as well and the Group's owner is set to the Super User account. So, I reckon there's something wrong with the migration_lookup processing part. I have read numerous tutorials on how to use that and it looks fine to me. I also read that migration_lookup fails silently if there is an error which makes it hard to debug.

Looking at the migration map table in the database it looks fine too:

```
mysql> select * from migrate_map_users limit 1;
+-----------------+----------------------+---------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+------+
| source_ids_hash | sourceid1            | destid1 | source_row_status | rollback_action | last_imported | hash |
+-----------------+----------------------+---------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+------+
| 009d...234ef457 | john.doe@example.com |     118 |                 0 |               0 |             0 |      |
+-----------------+----------------------+---------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Due to the migration dependency through

```
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - migrate_plus.migration.users
```

the User migration should also run first, but it still doesn't work. Even after both migrations have run through, I tried an update migration run, but the Group's owner is never set (stays at being 0/Anonymous).

Is there soemthing wrong with my yml file? Are there other means to connect user and groups?

Answer (score 0):

s/migrate_plus.migration.users/users/

The "migrate_plus.migration." is not part of the migration plugin ID - it is only part of the filename for the config entity.

Comment: Since all tutorials actually write just `users`, I tried that first, of course, but it never worked at all. Thus, I started using `migrate_plus.migration.users` and then the reference happened. For my specific problem, I ended up using `entity_lookup` instead of `migration_lookup` as a workaround.